# Closing Active Accordion panel on click... there seems to be one panel open at all times

Tags: jquery, accordion

http://jsfiddle.net/buhlett/paw5w/

The accordion works smoothly but it doesn't allow me to close all the panels at any one time. One panel is forced open at all times.

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing a line or two

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Store variables
var accordion_head = $('.grape-accordion > li > a'),
    accordion_body = $('.grape-accordion li > .grape-sub-menu, .grape-last-sub-menu');
// Open the first tab on load
// Click function
accordion_head.on('click', function(event) {
    // Disable header links
    event.preventDefault();
    // Show and hide the tabs on click
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
        accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle('normal');
        accordion_head.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul class="grape-accordion">
        <li id="one" class="share"><a href="#one">-</a>
        <ul class="grape-sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><em>»</em>-</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="two" class="mail"><a href="#two">-</a>
        <ul class="grape-sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><em>»</em>-</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="two" class="mail"><a href="#two">-</a>
        <ul class="grape-sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><em>»</em>-</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code here. Specify your problem here. We appreciate the demo, but without the code here the question becomes worthless to everyone if (when) JS Fiddle falls over. Close the active accordion on clicking *what* element?

Comment: Will do, sorry new here.

Comment: I want the accordion to close when you click the button that opened it in the first place.. in this case.. the header. However, I will be changing the button that fires these actions to a smaller button on the header.. something like a comments button, so i need the code to be simple and flexible... anything will help me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/paw5w/1/)**? If so, all I did was add an else clause.

```
else {
        accordion_body.slideUp('normal');
        accordion_head.removeClass('active');
    }
```